# loading value from a button to an external page

Tags: jquery, ajax

i would like to get the value of a button when i click on a it.
im very new to jquery so please help, i am trying to load or post a value from a button 
 on a external page. these values are loaded from a DB so each button is given a different number.
    eg:     
             input type="button" value="1" />
        input type="button" value="2" />
        input type="button" value="3" />
             
    when i click on 'button 1' i would like to post 1 to an
    external page that popup and display button 1 was clicked.

my code is been done using a tooltip instead of a popup but i believe its the same idea.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#qtip a[rel]').each(function(){
   $(this).qtip({ content: {
        text: '<img src="img/preloader.gif" alt="loading..." />',
        url: $(this).attr('rel'), 
        title: { text: 'Flag This', button: 'Close' }
     },
     position: { corner: {target: 'bottomMiddle', tooltip: 'topMiddle' },
        adjust: { screen: true  }
     },
     show: { when: 'click', solo: true },
     hide: 'unfocus',
     style: { tip: true,  border: {width: 0, radius: 4},
        name: 'light', 
        width: 340 
     }   })  });});
</script>
```

this is a link that when click on it, it opens up the page as a tooltip. i want to be able to grab the value
and then post it to the tooltip. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have pasted irrelevant code for your requirement.

make same class name for all buttons and run below code for getting value of button clicked.

```
$(function() {
    $(".btnclassname").click(function() {
        var clkId = $(this).attr('value');
    });
});
```

else you can try with parent div for all buttons

```
$(function() {
    $("#parentdivId input:button").click(function() {
        var clkId = $(this).attr('value');
    });
});
```